# Prism Navigation - Navigate user to different page when certain condition is met

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I use Xamarin.Forms with Prism 7.2. There used to be a method `OnNavigatingTo` in prior versions of Prism, but this method was removed in 7.2. I'm not sure how to achieve this behavior:

- In every PageViewModel I want to run some code and if specific condition is met, I need redirect user to different page. **For example, if there is no user logged, I want to redirect him to login page. Or if user's consent has expired, I want to redirect him to consent page.**

I used `OnNavigatingTo` for this. I simply checked my conditions and called `NavigationService.NavigateAsync("xy")` if needed. This worked just fine.
However, this method was removed and I don't know how to achieve this behavior in new version of Prism.

I tried to put this code to `OnNavigatedTo` or `Initialize`. The problem is that this won't stop the current navigation and it will navigate to the wrong page anyway.

How could I handle this scenario?

- I can run navigate to login/consent page in `OnNavigatedTo` in some timeout, so the user will be navigated normal page and then, after it's rendered, to login/consent page. But I don't like this solution, it seems to be quite hacky to me
- Can I override Prism `NavigationService` somehow and handle this in `NavigationAsync` method? However, I'm not sure whether I can even override this service and moreover, this service/method should does what it's intended for - to navigate where it's asked and not any checks and redirects...
- Is there any other solution I didn't notice?...

Comment: You could check the redirection criteria before doing the navigation. You could even wrap it in your own state machine, so that your code never directly accesses the built-in navigation service, but something that can satisfy your requirements (e.g. if an item view is requested, go to login first, if the user is not logged in then continue to the item view, if the user is allowed to view the item, otherwise go to the access denied screen).

Comment: The `OnNavigatingTo(), `OnNavigatedTo()` methods were dropped because it wasn't clear how people should use them. Instead when you want to pass data to a view model use `IInitialize` and when you want to handle conditions when being navigatd to/from use `INavigationAware`. Adding this interface to your viewmodel should restore the previous behaviour from 7.2